# Data from 2 or more database tables to one Java object

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Let's say I have a database schema like this (not enough reputation to post images)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yT4v.png

How would you connect those tables and all it's data to one Java object?

I know how to make an Java object from that Person table, but how can I use that below "addItem" method to add all the items what he have in other table (I know this may not work, but just for explanation what I am looking for)?

```
public class Person {

private int id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private List<Item> personItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

//getters and setters for id, firstname, lastname

public void addItem(Item item){
    this.personItems.add(item);
}
}
```

I query all the items what one person has like this:

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.Firstname, p.Lastname, i.name
FROM Person as p, PersonItem as pi, Item as i
WHERE p.PersonID=pi.PersonID AND pi.ItemID = i.ItemID AND p.PersonID=?;
```

So if person has 4 items the query result is 4 lines. But what I really want is one line and all results from "i.name" column. Otherwise comes "Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 4" and it's stupid to save all the results to list.

This is a style what I have used so far with making an object from one table. But now I need more data from other tables to that one object. Is there any easy way to implement this?

```
public Person findPerson(int id){
String sql = "select .. from .. where id=?";
Object[] parameters = new Object[]{id};

RowMapper<Person> mapper = new PersonRowMapper();
Person p = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, mapper);

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to something like this:

```
SELECT i.name
FROM Item as i
WHERE i.ItemID IN (
    SELECT ItemID 
    FROM PersonItem 
    WHERE PersonID IN (
        SELECT PersonID
        FROM Person
        WHERE PersonID = ?
    )
)
```